# Given complex eigenvalues, with its complex-conjugates also as eigenvalues, how can I construct a matrix with real entries?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

Given a list of complex eigenvalues, where the eigenvalues' complex-conjugates are also in the list, how can I construct a matrix with *real* entries that has this list as its spectrum?

Comment: It suffices to solve this problem for a single complex eigenvalue and its conjugate. Do you know the eigenvalues of a rotation matrix?

Comment: Note that the block matrix
$$
\pmatrix{A&0\\0&B} 
$$
has the eigenvalues from $A$ combined with the eigenvalues from $B$.

Comment: @user58865: almost; you need to multiply by $r$ after putting your pairs of complex eigenvalues into polar form. But yes, that's the argument I had in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- generate the characteristic polynomial $$p(x):=\Pi_{k=1}^n(x-\lambda_k)(x-\bar \lambda_k)=\Pi_{k=1}^n(x^2-2 (\Re{\lambda_k})x+|\lambda_k|^2)$$ which has real coefficients.

  - then take the **companion matrix** associated with $p(x)$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix).

Answer (score 1):

- Compute its characteristic polynomial $p$ with the leading coefficient $1$ and other coefficients $a_i$.
- Than, your matrix is

$$
        \left[\begin{matrix}
         & 1 & & &  \\
         &  & 1 &&  \\
        &  &  & \ddots& \\
        &  &  & & 1 \\
        a_{n - 1} & & \cdots& a_1 & a_0
        \end{matrix}\right]
$$